# Is it possible to click on links(not buttons) inside a <form>?

Tags: xpath, codeception

If I have something like this:

```
<form>
<input type="submit" style="display: none;">
<a href="......">link</a> 
</form>
```

How can I test the link?
This works:

```
$I->seeElement('//form/');
```

But for this I get:

```
Element located either by name, CSS or XPath element with '//form/a' was not found.:
$I->seeElement('//form/a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the link how?  For clarity lets say the text for your link is "Text".

You can click the link:
$I->click('Text');
      or
$I->click(['link' => 'Text]);

or you can see the link
$I->seeElement(['link' => 'Text']);
     or 
$I->canSeeElement(['link' => 'Text']);